# Python Error - TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain why I can not use your_name in the goal variable?

```
my_name = "Bryson"
my_age = 29
your_name = input ("What is your name? ")
your_age = input ("What is your age? ")
print ("My name is", my_name,", and I am", my_age, "years old.")
print ("Your name is", your_name,", and you are", your_age,".")
print("Thank you for buying my book,", your_name,"!")
goal = input ("What was your favorite part of the book,", your_name, "?")
print("Awesome!")
```

The error I get is:

```
goal = input ("What was your favorite part of the book,", your_name, "?")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Comment: read https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 2):

You got that error because you in fact gave 3 arguments to the `input` function when it was only expecting 1 (namely, a string prompt).

```
In input ("What was your favorite part of the book,", your_name, "?")
           ---------------------------------------- , ---------, ---
```

The underlined parts are the comma-separated arguments: a string ("What is ....book", a variable `your_name`, and another string, "?"

I think what you wanted was

```
goal = input("What was your favorite part of the book, " + your_name + "?")
```

Here the concatenation operator `+` combines those ingredients into a single string -- and a string is the one argument that `input` is expecting

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "giving 3 arguments" in more layman's terms? Furthermore, can you also indicate how I can tell the program to expect 3 arguments instead of 1?

Comment: And the plus signs worked! But can you explain what the + signs are telling the program?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`goal = input ("What was your favorite part of the book, %s ?" % your_name)`

[image]

Comment: When I run the program, with that line of code you gave me, it skips over that question (What was your favorite part of the book, your_name?).

Comment: @Ben I give a screen shot of my answer, is that what you want?

Answer (score -1):

```
input(print("What was your favorite part of the book, " + your_name + "?"))
```

Comment: The argument of your input function will be `None` since `print` returns `None`. If you want to use the `print` statement, you need to move it out to before the `input` function, and have the `input` empty.